# ADB Shell command not applied - "am set-standby-bucket" - Android 9

Tags: adb, shell, standby

Currently trying to observe the behaviour of my app in different adaptive battery buckets on Android **Pie**. I was testing it with the command :

```
adb shell am set-standby-bucket <packagename> <active|working_set|frequent|rare>
```

(documented here : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power)

The problem is that the command appear to be ignored by the device as you will see in the actual behavior snippet.

Notice that only **one** device is plugged during the process.

**Actual behaviour :**

```
$ > adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
$ > adb shell am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 10
$ > adb shell am set-standby-bucket <package-name> rare
$ > adb shell am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 10
```

or

```
$ > sudo adb shell
$ > su
# > dumpsys battery unplug
# > am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 10
# > am set-standby-bucket <package-name> rare
# > am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 10
```

**Expected behaviour :**

```
$ > adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
$ > adb shell am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 10
$ > adb shell am set-standby-bucket <package-name> rare
$ > adb shell am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 40
```

or

```
$ > sudo adb shell
$ > su
# > dumpsys battery unplug
# > am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 10
# > am set-standby-bucket <package-name> rare
# > am get-standby-bucket <package-name>
> 40
```

Here is my configuration :
*Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
MacBook Pro - MacOS Mojave 10.14.3*

Here is the device configuration I am using :

- Type : Emulator
- Name: Pixel_API_28
- CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom    (x86_64)
- Path: ..../.android/avd/Pixel_API_28_1.avd
- Target:    google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 28)
- image.androidVersion.api: 28
- tag.id: google_apis

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3):

I see the same thing with the Android P emulator.
However, this works for me on a Pixel 2 device with P.

Btw I think you need to use the integer representation when setting:

```
adb shell am set-standby-bucket <package-name> 40
```

Not

```
adb shell am set-standby-bucket <package-name> rare
```